# PHP Code obfuscation

Tags: php, obfuscation

I had a php obfuscation program a while ago but I forgot what it was called.  It could obfuscate code, and confuse people who knew a little php.

Here's what an obfuscated example looks like:

```
<?php session_start();include("\x6c\x69b/\x62\x2f\x6d\x69nd/m\x61x\x2e\x70h\x70");${"G\x4c\x4f\x42A\x4cS"}["s\x69lv\x62g"]="\x70\x5ft\x69\x74\x6c\x65";$wdrvnbyeveu="\x70\x5ft\x69\x74\x6c\x65";secure();switch($_GET["\x64"]){case"r":${${"\x47L\x4f\x42AL\x53"}["s\x69\x6c\x76\x62\x67"]}="R\x65p\x6c\x79\x20\x74\x6f tick\x65\x74";include("l\x69b/\x74/repl\x79\x2ep\x68p");break;default:${$wdrvnbyeveu}="S\x75p\x70ort";include("lib/\x74/d\x65f\x61\x75l\x74.php");break;}include("li\x62/b/\x66\x6fot/kill.p\x68p");
?>
```

Does anyone know what program this was by looking at the example?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was actually looking for the same thing just a few days ago, and had no luck either.

Comment: Just wondering: what's the reasoning behind obfuscating PHP?  It's not a local-based language like Javascript.

Comment: @Switz: People sell packaged solutions and want to protect themselves from the buyer messing with the code or reselling it. People put solutions on shared servers, and don't want the server managers running away with the code.

Comment: Maybe it is one of this - take a look at e.g. [www.codecanyon.net](https://codecanyon.net/search/php%20encoder) and search for `php encoder`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bunch of PHP obfuscators.  Probably several of them can do something like this.

Our [Thicket PHP Obfuscator](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/PHPObfuscator.html) will obfuscate literal strings exactly this way, and will preserve system function identifiers such as "session_start" in this fashion, so it could be ours.

Comment: The "$wdrvnbyeveu" in the example is proof that it isn't ours. I won't say how I know.